# trouble sending data to detailview

Tags: nsstring, uitextview

I am using collection view to get data from my server display some of it in a cell and then I have a segue to the destination view controller I got the image to update correctly but for some reason the text is not going to my UITextView

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
//DetailSegue

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DetailSegue"]) {
    ICBCollectionViewCell *cell = (ICBCollectionViewCell *)sender;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:cell];
    ICBDetailViewController *dvc = (ICBDetailViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];

    path = [paths objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    Path = [path objectForKey:@"path"];
    title = [titles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    Title = [title objectForKey:@"title"];
    sku = [SKUs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    Sku = [sku objectForKey:@"SKU"];
    longDescrip = [longDescription objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    LongDescrip = [longDescrip objectForKey:@"longDescrip"];
    LongDescrip =@"Hello World";
    NSLog(@"Descrip =%@",LongDescrip);
    NSString *iconTitle =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",Sku];
    NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",iconTitle]]; //add our image to the path

    dvc.img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
    dvc.title = Title;
    //UITextView *descrip = (UITextView *)[cell viewWithTag:120];
    [dvc.descrip setText:@"Hello"];
}
```

}

I am not sure if it has something to do with the fact that the object being sent to is a UITextView and I am sending it a String

or if I have something hooked up wrong

here is the .m  and  .h for the detailController also

the .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

   @interface ICBDetailViewController : UIViewController
   @property(weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
   @property (strong) UIImage *img;
   @property(weak) IBOutlet UITextView *descrip;

@end
```

the .m

```
#import "ICBDetailViewController.h"

    @interface ICBDetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation ICBDetailViewController

@synthesize imageView, img, descrip;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
   self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
   if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
   }
   return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   self.imageView.image = self.img;
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
   // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Hopefully somebody will see what I have missed for two days

Answer (score 0):

after again reviewing it all I noticed i missed the outlet in the .h and forgot to set it show in the ViewDidLoad of the .m I also missed hooking upthe referencing outlet to my txtView